# how to send Variables to other pages in login form

Tags: php, variables

i have a login form like this ,

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE user_email='".$user_email."' AND user_pass='".$user_pass."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername=$row['user_email'];
$dbpassword=$row['user_pass'];
$dbfirstname=$row['user_login'];

}

if($user_email == $dbusername && $user_pass == $dbpassword  )
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$dbfirstname;
$_SESSION['sess_email']=$dbusername;

/* Redirect browser */
header("Location:http://localhost/main/index.php");
}
}
?>
```

i want to know if someone logs into my website how can i put $_SESSION['sess_user'] and $_SESSION['sess_email'] in a Variable like $dbfirstname and $dbusername then use those in other pages as his/her name and insert it into specific database table

Comment: why don't you just use $_SESSION in other pages? Or don't I understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_pass = $_POST['password'];


if($query){
$_SESSION['login'] = $user_email;
}else{
exit;
}
```

you need to use the post to your forms

where name = "" in the forms you need to have the same thing in the $ _POST ['']

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start_session() should be the first line of the code in both the file, in which you are setting the session variable and get the session variable.

Here you are setting two session variable.

```
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$dbfirstname;
$_SESSION['sess_email']=$dbusername;
```

Now you need to start your session in your index file and assign session variable value to your php variable like this.

```
$dbfirstname = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
$dbusername = $_SESSION['sess_email'];
```